# How to unlock a Photon Q with an MSL code?

Tags: sim-card, sim-unlocking, att, sprint, motorola-photon

I'm having a strange issue with a Motorola Photon Q. The Photon Q is carrier locked to Sprint but has long since been paid off. I have the IMEI and the MSL code to unlock the device to use with other carriers, but I've hit a roadblock in actually getting it unlocked. I called Sprint and the guy that answered seemed very helpful. He tried to unlock the phone. He even read through the manual to try to make this work. In the end he talked to his supervisors and informed me that because of how old the Photon Q is they can't unlock it through IMEI and that I need to go to the carrier that the phone will be used with, AT&T, and have them unlock it using the MSL code. So, I went to AT&T to talk with them about unlocking it with the MSL code and they didn't even seem to know what an MSL code was. I explained to them exactly what the Sprint guy explained to me several times but they didn't seem to understand. They wanted the IMEI, which didn't work. They kept asking me if it was an AT&T phone. Nothing I said seemed to get through and I still don't know how to unlock this phone.

So, how do I unlock this phone, the Motorola Photon Q, to be used with non-Sprint carriers like AT&T?

Comment: `Devices manufactured prior to February 2015 in general, are not SIM unlock-capable.` [Sprint FAQ](https://www.sprint.com/en/support/solutions/device/faqs-about-unlocking-your-sprint-device.html). Your device is from 2012.

Comment: @Robert I know. As i said, the guy from Sprint said that. I have the MSL to take to AT&T and have taken it to them. They don't seem to even know what an MSL code is. As I stated above. According to Sprint AT&T can definitely use the MSL to unlock the phone to be used with AT&T.

Comment: @Robert also, despite what's been said and what you've linked to I know for a fact that it's completely possible to sim unlock a Motorola Photon Q because people have done it. I just don't know how to.

Comment: You know that is was possible to unlock this device, but not if it is still possible. As I said if the unlocking requires something special on provider side which has been switched off long ago then unlocking was working but not now. Also it seems like the new provider has to support unlocking. Read "I have the MSL code for my device. Does that mean that my device is unlocked?" of the FAQ.

Comment: @Robert That's not the question I'm asking so answers to it wouldn't help here. I know just having the MSL doesn't unlocked the device. I need to know how to use it to unlock the device or at least how to explain to AT&T what they need to do to unlock it since they don' seem to know.